# React js with bite deployment on azure

Tags: reactjs, node.js, azure, azure-devops

error npm@10.4.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0". Got "16.20.2"

**I got this error when i try to deploy react js with bite in azure static web app from github**

How can i solve this issue

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion below changing the version of node? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just update the node version from 16.20.2 to something in the range from "^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0".

In your package.json file, update the engines section.

```
"engines" : {
   "node": ">18.17.0"
},
```

Ref: https://edi.wang/post/2022/1/27/how-to-specify-nodejs-version-when-building-azure-static-web-app